# Check at least one checkboxlist item is selected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to check that at least one item in asp:checkbox list is selected and if at least one item is selected in checkboxlist then I want to enable button.

Please help

Comment: I want to do it in javascript..On the client side

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the link [Validating checkboxList Asp.Net control using javascript](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/2769-Validating-checkboxList-Asp-Netcontrol-javascript.aspx) for details. Please try:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function CheckItem(sender, args){     
    var chkControlId = '<%=chkMealPeriod.ClientID%> '    
    var options = document.getElementById(chkControlId).getElementsByTagName('input');    
    var ischecked=false;    
    args.IsValid =false;    
    for(i=0;i<options.length;i++)    
    {        
        var opt = options[i];        
        if(opt.type=="checkbox")        
        {                       
            if(opt.checked)            
            {                
                ischecked= true;                
                args.IsValid = true;                            
            }        
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: you could skip `args.IsValid = true` with `return true` so that OP wont be confused. you see, OP just want to enable a button when one of them is checked. +1 this is the way to go unless the client-side has jquery library in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("chkControlId[]");
    var okay=false;
    var l=checkboxs.length;
    for(var i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        if(checkboxs[i].checked)
        {
            okay=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!okay)
    {
        alert("Please Select atleast one");
    return false;
    }
```